# No Internet with Orbot

Tags: blocked-services

I'm running Orbot on a Samsung Galaxy S5 (g900f) with Resurrection Rom. My V3 Antivirus secures all my internet traffic, and I use Orbot for all my Internet traffic to anonymize it.

So when I start Orbot with launch button, after turning on the transparent mode for only 4-5 Apps, VPN, and Bridge Mode, Orbot connects but in Orfox search I got a 0/0kb download and upload rate.

After disconnecting Orbot, no Internet is working (Wlan, Mobile) it shows an ! in the status bar. Now I can't connect to Orbot anymore and using my browser shows me a DNS failure message.

What to do?

Comment: My guess is you're using Orbot with another firewall application and they're conflicting.

Comment: @canonizing ironize I check this, but i can't find ANY firewall Option on my Phone. I load no alternativ firewall on it. Noch nicht

Answer (score 1):

"My V3 Antivir Safes all my intern Datas"

There's your problem. Your antivirus app is interfering with your Internet traffic. Disable or uninstall the app, and Orbot should work just fine.

Of course, you don't really need antivirus on Android anyway: https://lmgtfy.com/?s=d&q=Do+I+need+antivirus+for+Android%3F